# Why is Han so skeptical of the force and the Jedi when Chewie had lots of experience with Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

Chewbacca is shown in the prequels working closely with Jedi, and in EU spent a lot more time with them. I can't imagine that Chewie doesn't recognize the Force as a real thing and know that Jedi are the real deal. But in *A New Hope* Han obviously does not put much stock in the Force or Jedi.

> “Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.”

But Han and Chewie have been close colleagues and friends for quite a while by then. How is it that Chewie has not shared his stories of his time with the Jedi enough that Han shows some evidence of knowing the Jedi are legit? Or how come Chewie doesn't rebut Han when he says the "Hokey religions" line? Is this just Lucas being bad at continuity or is there some retcon to explain it? Are Wookiees just not much for sharing personal history? Is Han and Chewie's relationship completely centered on the work they do together, maybe avoiding subjects of "politics & religion" like people in real life?

Comment: Even if Chewie has told Han, having possibly not witnessed any of it himself, Han may still be skeptical.

Comment: @phantom42 Like your good friend insisting they've been abducted by aliens or been visited by an angel or something? I could see that. Still seems weird given how close these guys are.

Comment: I think it has more to do with ep 1 - 3 never being written in the first place so when it came time to do so, Lucas' massive ego threw as many characters as he could in the prequels without concern for how their presence affected the original story. Maybe the subject either never came up between Han and Chewie or if it did, Han just blew it off the way I would if a scientologist started lecturing me on the truths of dianetics.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a strict canon proof, but:

1. Han isn't skeptical of the Jedi's existence - which is what Chewie can tell him. He's skeptical of the Force and its impact.

   > There's no mythical Force controlling **my** destiny

   Chewie cannot confirm or deny that to Han, as he isn't a Jedi and has no clue of the internal tenets of Jedi religion.
2. Jedi are outlawed.

   I don't really see Chewie start babbling to Han "hey, I used to work with Jedi... you know, before the Emperor paid $$$ bounties on anyone connected to them".

Comment: Good points, though not so sure that a smuggler would care about #2.

Comment: @ChrisO - a smuggler would care a lot more. He knows about how people get snitched on